# Restart express server every time a request is made to an endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

basically I would like to 'restart' it every time a client sends a request to /reset, how can I do that? any help is extremely valuable, I don't know how to approach this yet

Comment: Run a process monitor like PM2 that restarts your server whenever it stops and then have your server shut itself down with `process.exit()` when you want it to stop.  I must say it would not be normal for a public web server to restart itself when any client sends a particular request like `/reset`.  Maybe if it was a heavily authenticated route only available to certain credentials.

Comment: You have restart in 'quotes' there.  Do you literally mean you want to restart the server process--like to have node.exe terminate and have something external restart the process?  If so, that seems like a rather unusual request.  If not, then what do you actually hope to accomplish when you 'restart'?  Is there some state you're trying to reset?  What's the motivation here?  I feel like I need the whole story.  What motivated you to ask this question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @jfriend00 mentioned, You can use `pm2` like applications to monitor the process. Below is simple steps that can be followed.

**Node Js code:** Exit the process on route

```js
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
app.get("/", (_, res) => res.send("hello"));
app.get("/restart", (_, res) => {
  process.exit(0);
});

app.listen(8080, () => console.log("Server is running on :8080"))
```

**Run server using pm2 in watch mode:**

```sh
./node_modules/.bin/pm2 start app.js --watch
```

He also mentioned that you should not use this in the production environment. I support that statement. You should not use this approach in prod environment.